# Why TP-LINK TL-WN725 (rtl8188eu) is not working in Raspbian Buster?

Tags: networking, wifi, realtek

Can anyone tell me why rtl8188eu is not "just working" in vanilla Raspbian Buster?

I was using Raspbian Stretch until now, and all I had to do to configure wifi with my network card after flashing image to RPi Compute Module 3 was this:

```
# wpa_passphrase MySSID MyPass >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
# reboot

# ping google.com
# voila - everything works!
```

Now I decided to use Buster. My device is properly detected (I see Realtek 8188 it when I run `lsusb` or `lsmod`), but after adding my WiFi configuration to `wpa_supplicant.conf` - it doesn't work.

**What is going on?**

Comment: can you show the full content of `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` (hide the SSID and PSK of course

Comment: Try using Mr Engmans' script to get a working driver for your 8188eu.  http://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/install-wifi

Comment: *"I see it when I run lsusb"* -> That will happen no matter what, since it is just information provided by the device using the base USB protocol which will happen with any and all USB devices whether or not a driver exists for them (it is this information that is used to select a driver, if one is available).

Comment: What would confirm whether or not the driver is working or not on some level would be the output from `ip link`.